# Como implementar esse while not do Python em C?

Tags: python, c

Estou estudando um código em Python que preciso transformar para C, mas a parte que está me confundindo é esta:

```
while not(f1 == 0 and fn == 1):
    ...
```

Como seria esse mesmo código em linguagem C?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente, você terá assim que aceitar uma resposta).

Answer (score 4):

Não existe `while not`, existe o operador `not` que é independente do `while`.

Se quiser aplicar só o `not` tem que trocar este operador que usa a palavra em inglês pelo símbolo `!` que é o que C usa. Mas precisa usar no lugar correto.  E o `and` você troca por `&&`.

```
while (!(f1 == 0 && fn == 1)) {
```

Note que em C os parênteses do `while` fazem parte de sua construção e não servem para agrupamento de uma expressão. Como precisa agrupar tudo para aplicar o operador em toda a expressão então precisa criar outros parênteses.

Isto ocorre em Python porque nesta linguagem os parênteses não fazem parte da construção do `while`.

Então até o mais correto em Python seria assim:

```
while not (f1 == 0 and fn == 1):
```

É um espaço em branco que parece desnecessário, mas faz toda diferença para legibilidade, já que do jeito que estava escrito fica parecendo que é uma função.

Mas o mais correto é só inverter todos os sinais:

```
while (f1 != 0 || fn != 1) {
```

Assim economiza uma operação e pode até facilitar o curto circuito e economizar outra. E para quem conhece fica até mais legível.

Se tudo será negado então o que é igual vira diferente, e o que é um `and`, vira um `or`. Na verdade em Python deveria ser assim também:

```
while f1 != 0 or fn != 1:
```

Sem os parênteses que podem confundir quando converte de uma linguagem para outra. Assim fica mais claro que não existe `while not`, antes os parênteses e a falta de espaço dava a impressão do `while not` ser uma coisa só.

Vou mostrar exemplo de como fica fazendo isso. E que a inversão de todos operadores é o mesmo que aplicar o `!`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int f1 = 1;
    int fn = 1;
    printf("%d ", f1 == 0 && fn == 1);
    printf("%d ", !(f1 == 0 && fn == 1));
    printf("%d\n", f1 != 0 || fn != 1);
    f1 = 0;
    printf("%d ", f1 == 0 && fn == 1);
    printf("%d ", !(f1 == 0 && fn == 1));
    printf("%d\n", f1 != 0 || fn != 1);
    while (f1 != 0 || fn != 1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0R2hVg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lpjwajjs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/NotEqualAnd.c).

Não esqueça que em C, ao contrário do Python que usa indentação e só precisa abrir com `:`, tem que fechar as chaves quando o bloco encerra. Aí eu fiz um `while` sem bloco por isso encerrou com `;`. Mas mais comum é:

```
while (f1 != 0 || fn != 1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A tradução direta para C seria a seguinte:

```
while (!(f1 == 0 && fn == 1)) { ... }
```

No entanto, isso pode ser simplificado pelo uso da [**lei De Morgan**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan) para isso:

```
while (f1 != 0 || fn != 1) { ... }
```