# Usando && e || em vez de "if" e "else"

Tags: javascript, operadores, curto-circuito

Ultimamente vi alguns códigos que usam `&&` e `||` para substituir `if` e `else` , e ate para fazer verificações com menos código. Estou usando bastante essa técnica sem nenhum problema até então. Segue um código de exemplo:

```js
const bool = true
const foo = 'Abacate'
const bar = 'Maçã'

bool && alert( foo || bar )
```

Até então venho usando esse tipo de abordagem para descobrir os defeitos dela.

O meu problema é que eu não sei "o que é isso", se essa técnica tem um nome. Então eu não sabia como procurar na internet sobre boas práticas, sobre semântica e se vale a pena usar. Então farei algumas perguntas.

- **Qual o nome disso?**
- **Vale a pena usar?**
- **Vai dificultar a leitura de outros?**
- **Existe alguma boa prática relacionada ou algum cuidado que eu deva ter?**
- **Poderia citar exemplos de onde essa técnica é boa?**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre operadores && e ||](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274110/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-operadores-e)

Comment: O pessoal já respondeu muito bem à pergunta então só quero dar um conselho: jamais nomeie uma variável com o nome “bool”. Como “bool” é um tipo de dados em varias linguagens, incluindo c++, nomear uma variável com esse nome pode gerar muita confusão. Eu sei que em C não existe o tipo “bool” mas tente evitar... É como se eu nomeasse uma variável como “Integer” ou “Int” ou “Struct”... Evite nomear variáveis em C com o mesmo nome de palavras reservadas do C++... Fica a dica

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Qual o nome disso?

Expressão condicional. Só isto. Ele não substitui o `if` e `else` já que estes comandos são controle de fluxo imperativo, eles fazem muito mais do que está ocorrendo aí. Este mesmo código, sem mudar um espaço sequer, pode ser usado normalmente dentro de um `if`, incluindo obviamente um `else if`, ou pode ser usado como valor que atribui uma variável, ou como argumento em uma chamada de função, ou em qualquer lugar que possa usar um expressão. Claro que o mais correto é onde esperara-se um valor booleano (`false` ou `true`) para fazer sentido. O `if` é um lugar onde se espera isso, se atribuir para uma variável então ela será booleana, e se passar para uma função espera-se que o parâmetro seja um booleano.

Por acaso ainda tem uma outra coisa chamada curto circuito que foi amplamente respondido sobre até porque de tão útil que é existe em praticamente toda linguagem:

- [Qual a diferença e para que servem os operadores & e && e | e || em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/61296/101)
- [Interpretação sobre operadores lógicos em Java quanto ao curto-circuito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/363837/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre os operadores & e &&?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101)
- [Como implementar esse while not do Python em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/327407/101)

Note que quem tem a ação de curto circuito são os operadores relacionais específicos, não é a expressão como um todo, inclusive alguns operadores relacionais não tem essa característica, são específicos de dois deles.

Então por causa disto a avaliação de um segundo operando em um `||` só será executado se o primeiro operando for falso, já que se ele for verdadeiro toda a expressão já é considerada verdadeira, não importa mais "olhar" o outro, e por nem executar o que tem no outro você acaba tendo uma execução condicional. Com o operador `&&` ocorre o contrário, se o primeiro operando for falso o segundo não será executado porque não tem mais como a expressão toda ser considerada verdadeira e e ele nem tenta. Já com `|` ou `&` o segundo operando executaria normalmente sempre, e você poderia usar da mesma forma que usou no seu código com resultados bem diferentes e não atingindo o objetivo esperado.

> Vale a pena usar?

Depende do contexto, mas não vejo problema algum em usar isto, existe na linguagem para ser usado. As pessoas que sabem programar, mesmo, usam o tempo todo em todo tipo de código, é uma técnica fantástica de programação para simplificar código. Sempre vai existir quem abuse disto ou não use nunca.

Tem algumas pessoas que acham que você deve fazer isto:

```
if (status == true)
```

O argumento é que fica mais legível. Mas só é mais legível para quem não sabe programar. Qualquer pessoa pode usar isto pela razão que ela quiser, mas pegar um valor que já é um booleano e fazer uma comparação para gerar o mesmo booleano não faz sentido, só faz isso quem é obrigado ou não entende para que serve um `if` (muitas pessoas não entendem mesmo usando todos os dias). Isto é tão mais legível que isto:

```
return x + 0;
```

Assim fica mais legível que está retornando um inteiro`</ironia>`

> Vai dificultar a leitura de outros?

Não, a não ser que a pessoa não saiba o que isto faz, aí ela vai perguntar para alguém, vai aprender e vai usar normalmente. Tem zero problemas de legibilidade, se usar de forma adequada será legível. Óbvio que é possível escrever isto de forma ilegível, mas é caso específico e não é porque usou o curto circuito e não é porque usou a expressão condicional fora do `if`.

Se a pessoa não sabe isso e não entende, não é que estava ilegível, é que a pessoa ainda não sabe programar. Eu costumo dizer "Se você não sabe o que cada caractere do seu código faz, até mesmo o espaço em branco, você ainda não sabe programar". As pessoas conseguem produzir aplicação mesmo sem sabem programar, mas ela só domina o que está fazendo quando entende tudo o que está ocorrendo ali. Mesmo que ela nunca tenha visto isto antes na vida se ela dominasse o processo ela saberia o que é, já que aprendeu os fundamentos. Hoje as pessoas não aprendem mais os fundamentos, apenas decoram receitas de bolo e isto é um problema porque elas não conseguem fazer bons códigos para a situação.

Como eu disse antes não tem um mecanismo especial da linguagem acontecendo aí, apenas algo padrão sendo usado de forma esperta para alcançar um resultado. Quem entende todos os aspectos da programação lê isto com extrema facilidade. Quem não aprendeu deve aprender, não deve fugir dele.

## Estilo funcional

Algumas equipes podem preferir o estilo mais imperativo e exigir o uso do comando (`if`), então deve seguir o que a equipe manda. Outras equipes seguem o estilo mais funcional e então ele faz muito mais sentido. Hoje muita gente está adotando o estilo mais funcional em JavaScript e outras linguagens.

> Existe alguma boa prática relacionada ou algum cuidado que eu deva ter?

Esquece esse negócio de boas práticas. Eu tenho até uma palestra sobre isto. Boa prática é receita de bolo para quem não quer aprender a fazer certo. Aprenda o fundamento, entenda o porquê de tudo o que usa e não precisará de boas práticas a não ser como um guia auxiliar. Então nunca peça uma boa prática, peça uma fundamentação para algo.

Não faça um código complexo demais, não crie uma lógica com várias expressões condicionais aninhadas ou mesmo com comparações demais. Se tiver uma expressão total muito longa quem sabe seja o caso de quebrar em parte e guardar m variáveis ou ter funções que faça cada parte. Isto vale para qualquer expressão condicional e não só quando usa ele direto em uma expressão onde costuma se esperar um *statement* (que é o que fez). Principalmente tome cuidado com parenteses, em alguns casos coloque até onde não precisa para deixar mais claro o que será executado primeiro. Isto também vale para qualquer expressão condicional em qualquer lugar, não é específico para este uso.

> Poderia citar exemplos de onde essa técnica é boa?

Não acho que seja necessário se você entender o que foi dito acima. Se você precisa executar algo condicionalmente, esta forma atende o que deseja, gosta de códigos curtos, ou do estilo funcional pode usar. Só não abuse, como tudo em programação.

Um exemplo que eu vejo muito as pessoas fazendo:

```
if (status == true && valor > 10) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Tudo isto poderia ser só:

```
return status && valor > 10;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/IfElse.js).

Mais código para ler mais ilegível fica. Código de menos pode tornar ilegível também, mas só vale para casos onde falta informação relevante para seu código, este caso falta algo da linguagem, o `if`, e legibilidade tem a ver com a facilidade da pessoa que nunca viu aquele código entender ele. A pessoa nunca ter visto algo da linguagem que é ferramenta primária dela só indica que ela ainda não aprendeu tudo o que precisava para programar, o que ela deve fazer não é evitar isto, é se preparar para saber o que é na próxima, inclusive porque ela vai passar programar melhor de forma geral porque entende o que é uma expressão condicional como ela foi concebida e não por um entendimento errado pré concebido sem fundamento.

Answer (score 18):

```js
bool && alert( foo || bar )
```

Tem duas coisas distintas acontecendo aí, mas vamos lá.

**Qual o nome disso?**

Primeiro, o `bool &&`: Essa parte usa a [avaliação de curto-circuito](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalia%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_curto-circuito), presente em boa parte das linguagens modernas. O que ela faz é, resumidamente, evitar avaliar mais expressões booleanas que o necessário.

Veja que, em um `||`, se temos um `true`, já é suficiente para não precisarmos avaliar as próximas expressões (`true` ou qualquer coisa é sempre `true`), e a mesma coisa para um `false` em um `&&` (`false` e qualquer coisa é sempre `false`).
Assim, podemos trocar isso:

```
if (bool) alert(1)
```

Por isso:

```
bool && alert(1)
```

Pois se bool for falso, a parte `alert(1)` não vai ser avaliada (executada).

Agora, `foo || bar`: [null coalescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator). Basicamente, se `foo` for algum valor falseável (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, ...), o operador `||` retorna `bar` no lugar.

**Vale a pena usar?**

Avaliação de curto-circuito, dificilmente. A legibilidade é terrível, use um if a não ser que extremamente necessário.

Null coalescing, sim, é uma ótima alternativa para:

```
let var = foo != null ? foo : bar
```

Ou mesmo para um `if (foo == null) ...`. No geral, null coalescing é bem fácil de ler.

**Vai dificultar a leitura de outros?**

^

**Existe alguma boa prática relacionada ou algum cuidado que eu deva ter?**

Boa prática, creio que seria não usar o curto-circuito. Se usar, tenha certeza que você entende a ordem em que as expressões estão sendo avaliadas e qual operador leva a que fluxo de execução. Pra qualquer linguagem que não seja shell script, use um if no lugar.

**Poderia citar exemplos de onde essa técnica é boa?**

Shell script. Em scripts shell é comum ver linhas do tipo:

```
comando argumento1 argumento2 && echo DEU CERTO
```

Ou

```
comando argumento1 argumento2 || echo DEU ERRADO
```

Em shell, o `&&` e `||` dão um jeito bem direto de reagir a códigos de retorno de comandos.

**Edit:** Pensando depois, me veio mais um caso à cabeça em que o curto-circuito pode ser usado de forma clara e trazer vantagens em relação ao if, que é dentro do próprio if, quando nosso objeto pode ser nulo. Suponha que temos uma variável `x` que tem um objeto com um método `f` que retorna booleano, e queremos verificar o retorno desse método em uma condição.

Podemos fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
if (x.f()) {
  // ...
}
```

Mas em várias linguagens, objetos podem ser nulos. Quando são, não podemos chamar métodos dele, e assim ajustamos nossa condição para evitar erros:

```
if (x != null && x.f()) // ...
```

Ou:

```
if (x == null || x.f()) // ...
```

Dependendo do que queremos quando `x` for nulo. Note que, em expressões nessa forma, é bem fácil entender a lógica por trás do que está sendo feito, e o curto-circuito é bem intuitivo.

---

**Obs.:** Essas coisas ficam mais evidentes se a gente entende como a "implementação" do `||` e do `&&` as seguintes funções:

```
function or(a, b) {
  if (a)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}

function and(a, b) {
  if (!a)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo.
Se eu intendi bem && pode ser usado com curto circuito (Diminuindo análise desnecessária de código).

|| pode ser usado como null coalescing (Facilitando atribuições que são truthy)

Comment: Sim. Ambos podem ser usados como curto circuito, na verdade, mas o `&&` funciona como um `if (bool)` e o `||` funciona como um `if (!bool)`. A propriedade de null coalescing do `||` vem da implementação que eu passei: se o valor à esquerda é falso, ele retorna o valor da direita.

Comment: Não acho que seja _null coalescing_ nesse caso (e nem "_falsy coalescing_")... ambos são _short-circuit evaluation_ usados para propósitos diferentes...